# how to ensure older branch can still be rebased when attempt to pull request back to main branch?

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control, rebase

I have a workflow that works like this:

1. branch off from main branch to create a version branch e.g. v1.1.1
2. branch off from version branch to create a feature branch e.g. feature/001-add-x
3. When do a pull request from feature branch back to version branch, try to do a rebase and merge
4. When do a pull request from version branch to master branch, try to do a rebase and merge

Sometimes, I get conflicts when I try to do a rebase and merge.

One scenario is like this:

1. There is a pull request on v1.1 to master branch awaiting approval.
2. Because we want to move quickly, we branch off a v1.2 from master branch **before** v1.1 was rebased and merged back to master.
3. We branch off another feature branch from v1.2 successfully
4. after completing the feature branch, we pull request and then rebased and merged back to v1.2 successfully
5. at this time, the pull request on v1.1 is accepted and it is rebased and merged back to master.
6. now we send a pull request on v1.2 to merge to master.
7. we noticed that github says while merge is possible, we will have conflict if we choose rebase and merge

I have thought of a possible way to avoid this which is to always branch off a new version branch **after** the master branch approves all preceding pull requests on older version branches.

But I was wondering if there is a way to allow rebase and merge while not waiting for all the older version branches to be successfully merged back to master branch

Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to **merge with rebase** for the newer version branch  on github directly (if the newer version branch and the older version branch both changed same files). But the work around is rebase the newer version branch locally and then merge with rebase by PR. We can illustrate by below graphs:

Assume the commit history original as below:

```
           G---H   V1.2
          /
...---A--B--C      master
             \
              D---E---F   V1.1
```

After `V1.1` branch merged with rebase into `master` branch, the commit history will be:

```
           G---H   V1.2
          /
...---A--B--C---E'---F'      master
             \
              D---E---F   V1.1
```

If `V1.1` branch and `v1.2` branch changed same files, github pull request will stop you to merge `v1.2` into `master` branch with rebase since there has conflicts.

The work around is to rebase `v1.2` branch on the top of `master` branch after the PR merge `v1.1` into `master` is completed. You can use the commands in local branch:

```
git checkout v1.2
git pull origin master --rebase
# resolve the conflicts in local repo
git pull origin v1.2 -f
```

Then the commit history will be:

```
                       G'---H'   V1.2
                      /
...---A--B--C---E'---F'      master
             \
              D---E---F   V1.1
```

Now you can merge `V1.2` branch into `master` branch with rebase, and there won't has conflicts for the PR on github.

Comment: so i do these steps `git checkout v1.2
git pull origin master --rebase
# resolve the conflicts in local repo
git pull origin v1.2 -f` locally on my own laptop first before I try to merge v1.2 into master on the github repo yes?

Comment: Another related question is right now, we only know if a pull request will suffer rebase conflicts when we try to do it to the github repo. Is there a way to check locally whether a would-be pull request is likely to have rebase conflict before we do so?

Comment: Yes, you should use these commands to resolve the conflicts in local repo. And If you want to know the rebase conflicts before resolving them, you can use the commands: `git fetch` and `git diff origin/master..origin/v1.2`, if there show the files which are changed for both of the two branches, that's the conflict files when you merge with rebase in PR.